# Questions related to transform.rotate() in Unity Scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have four rectangular platforms put around a square platform. All other three rectangular platforms were rotated from the '0' platform. On the end of each rectangular platforms, I set up some spawn points to generate cubes with arrows sign on its face(the image of this cube is shown in the second link). I hope to rotate the cube to change the orientation of the arrow on it. But my original codes that rotating the cube do not work for platform 1 & 3, but work for platform 0&2.

Although I have found how to change it to make it works, I still cannot understand why my original codes failed. The version I used is 2019.4.18f1.

The top view of these platforms are shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZYV1.png)

**Unworkable way**

dirCubeTypes is an array that stores all my different kinds of cube objects.
dirCubePoints is an array that stores all my spawn points.
The first statement works well. The problem is in the second statement.

```
GameObject cube = Instantiate(dirCubeTypes[Random.Range(0, 6)], dirCubePoints[Random.Range(0, 4)]);
cube.transform.Rotate(transform.forward, 90 * Random.Range(0, 4));
```

The figure below shows the cube generated on the platfrom 3. I want it to rotate around z-axis, but the codes above make it rotate around its x-axis instead of z-aixs. I know the third parameter is relativeTo, and the default value is Space.self. **Why doesn't the codes above make it rotate along the z-axis in its own local coordinate system?**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sySiO.png)

**Workable ways**

I have tried out three workable ways, but for two of them, I still don't know why it works.

This one works well. If I use Vector3.forward in Space.self, I think it should rotate around the x-axis of the cube itself, but it rotate around its z-axis.

```
GameObject cube = Instantiate(dirCubeTypes[Random.Range(0, 6)], dirCubePoints[Random.Range(0, 4)]);
cube.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 90 * Random.Range(0, 4));
```

This one also works well. But I am confused either.

```
GameObject cube = Instantiate(dirCubeTypes[Random.Range(0, 6)], dirCubePoints[Random.Range(0, 4)]);
cube.transform.Rotate(transform.forward, 90 * Random.Range(0, 4), Space.World
);
```

The last one is the only one that works as I think.

```
GameObject cube = Instantiate(dirCubeTypes[Random.Range(0, 6)], dirCubePoints[Random.Range(0, 4)]);
cube.transform.RotateAround(transform.position, transform.forward, 90*Random.Range(0,4));
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what your question is and what you intend to happen with your example. Are you trying to spawn cubes at hand-placed Transforms? If that is the case, then orient them in the direction you want and spawn them at Quaternion.Identity instead of rotating them. When you do this, it will spawn the direction that the spawn point is facing. I am also a little confused about the Random.Range for the rotation. Care to explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve with that?

Comment: I am very sorry for the vague explanation and I have now amended it.

Comment: All cubes are supposed to face to the square platform after they are instantiated, and there is no problem here. Then since there is an arrow on each cube, I hope to rotate the cube. The expected result is that the arrow can randomly indicate upward, downward, left or right directions.

Comment: When you say upward, downward, etc. do you mean relative to the object or in world space? As each object as a transform.[axail direction] but there is also a world counterpart to each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

- [`Vector3.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) just equals `new Vector3(0,0,1)` so it is just a generic **Z** axis vector (either in the world or local depending on how it is used)
- [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) rather is the local **Z** axis of your object in **world space**

And [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) can either be used in **world space** or in **local space** (this is the default since the space parameter is [**optional**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) and defaults to `Space.Self`).

When you passed in

```c#
cube.transform.Rotate(transform.forward * 90 * Random.Range(0,4));
```

it of course behaves strange since you treat the **world space** vector `transform.forward` like a **local space** one. So as soon as your object is somehow rotated in the world it breaks.

---

So either you want the world space then do

```c#
// Using the world space transform.forward and passing in Space.World
cube.transform.Rotate(transform.forward * 90 * Random.Range(0,4), Space.World);
```

or the same in local space

```c#
// Using the local space Vector3.right
// in this case - since it will use Space.Self if nothing is passed in -
// the Vector3.forward is treated as relative to the local space
cube.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * 90 * Random.Range(0,4));
```

Comment: Thanks. I had previously misunderstood that since transform.forward could change with the rotation of the object, it was used in local space.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your question update. I believe your misunderstanding stems from not knowing what `Vector3.forward` and `Transform.forward` are and their core difference. `Vector3.forward` is the unit vector defined by (0, 0, 1). The `Transform.forward` is a relative direction based on the orientation of your object.

Your first example works in some cases as it just so happens that the `Transform.forward` and `Vector3.forward` happen to be the same direction.

Your second example works as you are using `Vector3.forward` not the relative `Transform.forward`

Your third example works as you provide the `Space.World`, so instead of using local orientations, it is rotating the object in world space relative to the scene.

Your fourth example works as you are using `RotateAround`. `RotateAround` is different than `Rotate` in that it will rotate the transform about your inputted axis (transform.forward), which pass through the point (transform.position) in world coordinates by the angle (90*Random.Range(0,4)) degrees. Effectively moving the local rotation around an axis back to world space.

I hope this clears up why the first example does not work while the last three do.